# Structural Equation Modelling vs Mixed Effects Model

Tags: mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, psychology

I have a question regarding what type of statistical analysis works best for my study design.

The research question is finding out what variables predict why a psychotherapy intervention is effective for certain people and not others. The study will be conducted over a 12 week period and collect weekly questionnaire scores indicating level of low mood.

Possible variables that predict the effectiveness of the intervention may include baseline depression score, psychiatric history, engagement, medication usage, demographics etc.

What would be the best approach to learn for this type of statistical analysis? It seems that SEM or Linear/Non-linear mixed effects model would be most suitable, but I am looking for some advice and confirmation that I'm at least going down the right track, or should I be looking to do something completely different?

Comment: I don't know your study problem well enough to answer, but why not do both at the same time? They are not mutually exclusive modelling approaches.

Comment: Its hard to know why a structural equation model would be appropriate without knowing the general path you are considering For example, do you have more than one dependent variable? What are they? How do predictors map onto each? Are there latent variables you are considering? For the mixed model, you need some kind of nesting structure. It sounds like you are doing some kind of repeated measures experiment (each sub is measured 12 times) which would qualify for a mixed model. As Galen mentioned, these can be technically combined, but more info is required to fully answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific! 
Study has one dependent variable (score on the PHQ-9), which is a measure of depression (latent variable). Measure will be collected throughout the intervention across a 12 week period. Will also be an additional baseline PHQ-9 score collected pre intervention.
I have not decided on what all of the predictors are but some likely to be categorical (e.g psychiatric history, medication usage, which will be coded somehow). Others continuous such as the baseline score, sessions attended, some other questionnaire scores, etc. Some will (probably) covary.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a latent change score (SEM) model in which you could examine which independent variables predict inter-individual differences in change across time. Such a modeling approach would require you to have multiple indicators (e.g., items, test halves, subscales) for your dependent variable.

See, for example:

McArdle, J. J. (2009). Latent variable modeling of differences and changes with longitudinal data. Annual Review of Psychology, 60, 577-605.

Raykov, T. (1993). A structural equation model for measuring residualized change and discerning patterns of growth or decline. Applied Psychological Measurement, 17, 53-71.

Steyer, R., Eid, M., & Schwenkmezger, P. (1997). Modeling true intraindividual change: True change as a latent variable. Methods of Psychological Research - Online, 2, 21–33. https://www.psycharchives.org/en/item/e81728c7-926a-47a0-91a2-72d33de92360

Steyer, R., Partchev, I., & Shanahan, M. (2000). Modeling true intra-individual change in structural equation models: The case of poverty and children's psychosocial adjustment. In T. D. Little, K. U. Schnabel & J. Baumert (Eds.), Modeling longitudinal and multiple-group data: Practical issues, applied approaches, and specific examples (pp. 109–126). Hillsdale, NJ: Erlbaum.

Comment: My dependent variable is depression score on the PHQ9. Whilst it's a validated measure and commonly used, it's also a relatively small questionnaire (9 items), and so I don't think that it would be possible to draw subscales from this. 

I'm assuming that this would imply this approach is not suitable?

Comment: You could create two (or three) indicators, for example, by randomly assigning items to two test halves ("item parcels") or use the items as indicators directly (9 indicators is a lot though).